# Best way to generate data to fill USB memory?

Tags: usb, auto-generate

I need to fill a USB memory and I want others to be able to repeat this in an easy way. SO I dont want to write "find a file that filles the memory" so they have to look around for such a file.

Rather I want to generate X MB of data and write that to a file that can then be transferrred to the USB stick.

How would you do that (on Windows)?

Comment: What is your platform? Windows? Linux? OSX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on Windows, you can use `fsutil`:

```
fsutil file createnew D:\fatboy.tmp SIZE
```

If you are on Linux or OSX or somesuch, you can use `mkfile` to make a big file:

```
mkfile SIZE PathToFileOnUSB
```

e.g.

```
mkfile 10m /some/where/on/USB/10MegFile
```

Or, if your system lacks `mkfile`, use `dd` to fill storage quickly and easily.

So, if you want 10MB, use:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=PathToFileOnUSB bs=1m count=10
```

That says... dump data, reading from `/dev/zero` (which supplies an endless sream of zeroes) and writing to the file called `PathToFileOnUSB` using a blocksize (`bs`) of 1 megabyte, and do this 10 times (`cnt`).

If you want X MB, use:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=PathToFileOnUSB bs=1m count=X
```

If you want to fill the device, write until error without specifying a count:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=PathToFileOnUSB bs=1m
```

Comment: If you see the error `dd: Invalid number '1m'`, you are using GNU dd. Use the same command but replace `bs=1m` with `bs=1M`